# Create new Pandas columns based on conditional counts of all other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I have a Pandas data frame with around ~360 columns.
I want to add another column to the other frame based on the count of whether in rest of the columns how many columns have a value greater than 0. Type of all my columns is float 64.

If this is my original dataframe

```
column A column B column C ...............Column Z 
0          1.5      6.77                   3.33
3.5        4.5      0                       0  
0           0       0.98                    0
.
.
.
2.35      4.32       0                      9.21
```

I want to add a column to it like this which have count of all non zero columns for each row:

```
column A column B column C ...............Column Z  Column New
0          1.5      6.77                   3.33        3
3.5        4.5      0                       0          2
0           0       0.98                    0          1
.                                                      .
.                                                      .
.                                                      .
2.35      4.32       0                      9.21       3
```

How can i add a column like this?
I was trying this but getting all NaNs.

```
df['column_new']=df.apply(lambda x: (x > 0).count())
```

Not sure if this is the correct way approach this.

Just to give an idea this is how values in my original data frame are like. So i want a count of columns in the new column which don`t have zero value.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. The comparison to zero returns series of bools, so you can sum rather than count. You also don't need to `apply` this since you can compare the entire dataframe and then sum along the correct axis:

```py
df = df.assign(count_gt_zero=(df > 0).sum(axis='columns'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option with [`gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html):

```
df['new_column'] = df.gt(0, axis=1).sum(axis=1)
```